# HTML5 WebSocket on iPhone 3GS

Tags: iphone, html, websocket

I'm developing a web app that needs to use HTML5 websockets.

Is there any way of incorporating a javascript-based library to interface with my WebSocket server, when the browser doesn't support the WebSocket protocol?

I've seen some Flash-based fallbacks, but I don't believe the iPhone supports Flash?

I'm using iPhone OS 4.1 and Safari 4.0.5.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: I'm using Socket.IO for this. Works very well.

Comment: I would appreciate it if you could clarify how you got nodejs installed on iPhone.

Comment: You need to include the javascript files inside a web view

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't understand. Nodejs is based on the v8 Javascript engine from Google. And, socket.io is based on Nodejs. So, don't I need to install both the v8 engine and the nodejs framework before I can call the javascript scripts from a web view?

Comment: @PLG: I'm guessing he's talking about just the client side. `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`